# Creating Anomaly Detection algorithm

Tags: outliers, moving-average, anomaly-detection

I am interested in the time series anomaly detection for security log files. I found cases similar to mine at the following link: [Time Series Anomaly Detection with Python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121134/time-series-anomaly-detection-with-python?rq=1). At the end of the page one of the experts (Mr. Keiven) said: "*... take a rolling X period moving average, subtract current metric value from the moving average.*" I was asked about some step by step details about his algorithm: this is the whole story. If you have understood the approach, I will appreciate any explanations.

Comment: Look into *robust* filtering algorithms.